# I have a sum which I can really easily show to be convergent, but Wolfram Alpha says it diverges. Is this a bug in Wolfram or is my proof flawed?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, wolfram-alpha

The sum is extremely simple: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2+(\cos{n})^2}}$.

The proof of convergence is elementary and is as follows:

Since $(\cos{n})^2 \geq 0$ for all positive $n$, we have $0<\frac{1}{n^{2+(\cos{n})^2}} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. Then by direct comparison, the sum converges.

This is trivial enough that I would expect a middle-schooler to be able to follow the argument, but somehow  WA gets it wrong. Since WA is very powerful, I'm now somewhat suspicious about my proof, (although it seems pretty airtight). Is this a Wolfram bug or is my proof somehow flawed?

Here is the link to the sum in Wolfram: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+1%2F%28n%5E%282%2B%28cos%28n%29%29%5E2%29%29

Comment: Your proof is OK, the series converges.

Comment: It's definitely a bug. I've just sent feedback to WA on this case.

Comment: Are middle school students capable of understanding convergence of infinite series?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to motivate. Start with the easiest example: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}$ to give an intuitive example. Then we can prove the sum of an infinite geometric series (doesn't *really* need limits - only factoring, really). Once students are comfortable with the notion of convergence, we can introduce p-series, and that one proof that shows they converge for $p>1$

Comment: (I forget it exactly but it's the one that only used the DCT, and some clever abuse of the powers of two  self-contained (this one might take a while to make sure it's understood but it should work eventually.)) Then of course the direct comparison test and the inequalities are fairly easy to explain.


I will test this on some unsuspecting middle schoolers. one of the mfs bit me bc i wouldn't let him play on my phone.

Comment: a) In point of fact, we can strengthen the result by weakening the hypothesis. Each n-th term can have denominator n + (cos(n))^2 by the same argument. b) Furthermore, cos(n) cannot equal zero, for those stopping to worry about the possibility - and kind of a nice exercise to get students to think about. (Reason: the zeros of cosine are of the form pi/2 + k*pi or (k + 1/2)*pi, which cannot equal integer n owing to the irrationality of pi.)

Comment: Hi, @Dan, I have in the last month put my plan into action. It has failed miserably and I seriously overestimated their familiarity with basic properties of functions in general. oops!  (on the bright side i made the kid that bit me do a lot of work and he actually found it fun!! he's pretty smart lwk!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind Wolfram Alpha... You are correct, the series is convergent.

If you look more carefully to WolframAlpha's output, you'll see that "Standard computational time was exceeded". I believe this is the source of the (erroneous) conclusion.

Comment: I've just run WA within Mathematica (without time constraints). It still claims the series to be divergent. Looks rather like a bug.

Comment: @trancelocation Yes, it might be a bug. Mathematica does not report divergence.